# Связать бота в телеграм с базами данных

Tags: python-3.x, sql, база-данных, telegram-bot

Написал бота в телеграм но не работал раньше с базами данных, не выходит связать его с базой данных на SQL. Кто разбирается - буду благодарен любой помощи. Ниже в коде даны переменные(заказчик, материал и тд). Работники компании вводят через бота эти данные и они должны сохраняться в БД. Заранее спасибо!

```
import telebot
from telebot import types



zakazchik = ''  #Заказчик
staff = ''  #Оборудование
problem = ''  #Дефект
work = ''  #Работы
mat = ''  #Материал
worktime = ''  #Время работы
waytime = '' #Время в пути


bot = telebot.TeleBot("")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard= True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Регистрация')
    markup.add(item1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ниже вам нужно последовательно указать необходимые данные", reply_markup = markup)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def echo_all(message):
    if message.text == 'Регистрация':

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Заказчик")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_zakazchik)



def reg_zakazchik(message):
    global zakazchik
    zakazchik = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Оборудование")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_staff)

def reg_staff(message):
    global staff
    staff = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Дефект")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_problem)

def reg_problem(message):
    global problem
    problem = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Работы")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_work)

def reg_work(message):
    global work
    work = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Материал")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_mat)

def reg_mat(message):
    global mat
    mat = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Время работы")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_worktime)

def reg_worktime(message):
    global worktime
    worktime = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Время в пути")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_waytime)

def reg_waytime(message):
    global waytime
    waytime = message.text
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='yes')
    keyboard.add(key_yes)
    key_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='no')
    keyboard.add(key_no)
    question = "Заказчик:  " + zakazchik + ".   Оборудование:  " + staff + ".    Дефект:  " + problem + ".    Работа:  " + work + ".    Материалы:  " + mat + ".    Время работы:  " + worktime + ".    Время в пути:  " + waytime
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text = question, reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "yes":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Запись внесена в базу данных.")
    elif call.data == "no":
        name = ''
        surname = ''
        age = 0
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Нажмите кнопку "Регистрация" ещё раз')


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1132272/234134